# Moving cells to bottom of UITableView when swiped right with animation effect

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I am trying to implement swipe gestures on the UITableviewCells, so when the user swipes to right I want the cell to move to the bottom of the table with animation effect (**just like CLEAR app in iphone**). I have referred this link  http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jtgesturebasedtableviewdemo, and trying to implement it. below is my code which I have tried so far when the state is "right"

```
- (void)gestureRecognizer:(JTTableViewGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer commitEditingState:(JTTableViewCellEditingState)state forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
    UITableView *tableView = gestureRecognizer.tableView;

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (state == JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft) 
    {
        // An example to discard the cell at JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft
        [self.rows removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
    else if (state == JTTableViewCellEditingStateRight)
    {       

        ***NSString *selectedString = [self.rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     

        [self.rows removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
        //                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft]; 

       NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

       [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath        indexPathForRow:[self.rows count]-1 inSection:0]];          

        [self.rows insertObject:selectedString atIndex:[self.rows count]];        
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];*** 
    } 

    [tableView endUpdates];

    // Row color needs update after datasource changes, reload it.
    [tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadVisibleRowsExceptIndexPath:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:JTTableViewRowAnimationDuration];
}
```

So as you can see when the state is right I am trying to implement it but I am not understanding how to have a animation effect. So friends, I request to please go through this code and help me out.

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this and come with this solution, now I get the effect when I swipe the cell to the right and the cell moves to the bottom, but my cells are not updated , whenever I swipe cell to right,it takes the string of the cell which is at immediate below position of it . Not able to understand what I am missing

```
- (void)gestureRecognizer:(JTTableViewGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer commitEditingState:(JTTableViewCellEditingState)state forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = gestureRecognizer.tableView;
    [tableView beginUpdates];
     if (state == JTTableViewCellEditingStateRight)
    {

        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.rows count]-1 inSection:0]];          

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft]; 
    } 

    [tableView endUpdates];

    // Row color needs update after datasource changes, reload it.
    [tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadVisibleRowsExceptIndexPath:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:JTTableViewRowAnimationDuration];
}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

    NSString *selectedString = [self.rows objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];     

    [self.rows removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

    [self.rows insertObject:selectedString atIndex:[self.rows count]-1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` manages the layout of its cells itself.

You can accomplish what you want by:

1. ...judiciously telling the table view not the animate the affected cells, creating a copy view hierarchy and animating those views and then showing the table at its end state. *— or —*
2. ...subclassing the table view and reimplementing its animation logic. *— or —*
3. ...creating your own table view.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean the code which I have written when state  =  right , moves the cell to bottom of the table, and I want to know whether its correct

Comment: Hey @Jesper and some one said to use this line of code to move the cells                                                         NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.rows count] inSection:0]];

Comment: You're right, that's a new method; maybe that uses the same animation. In that case I'll retract my answer. But to do any type of animation that isn't supported, my answer stands.

Comment: but when I add this code of lines, when state = right, my app crashes, can u tell why

Comment: `self.rows.count` is one more than the last index in the table. If you have three rows, they will be at row index 0, 1 and 2, and count will be 3. Do `self.rows.count - 1` to target the last row.

Comment: Hi @Jesper, I updated the code according your suggestions, u can see my updated code above, but still app crashes, I get this in log JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo[1489:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046

Comment: Is it possible that you may not have a selected index path at that time? I am glad to help, but you will still need to write and debug your own code. You should make sure that having done these animations, the data source is consistent with them. It should agree that the row you made animate to the bottom is indeed the last row, and the rows it moved past should be offset by one index.

Comment: Ok Jasper, I will go through it once again and try to go according to ur directions and get back to u

Comment: Hi @Jasper, please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865326/issue-with-updating-the-datasource-while-moving-row-at-indexpath

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15058/discussion-between-ranjit-and-jesper)