# issue with updating the datasource while moving Row at IndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

I am trying to move a row from one position to another on swipe gestures, ie. when I swipe right any of the cell, the swiped cell should go to the bottom of the cell, for this I have written the code, and it works fine in some condition i.e suppose I swiped the cell at index position 0 it goes correctly to the bottom of the cell, suppose I have **"A, B, C"** in my array, so the table displays "A, B, C" .Now suppose I select **" A"** to swipe which is at position **0** it goes at bottom and and now the table will display **B,C,A** which is correct. Now I swipe **"C"** which is at postion **1** so that it should go to bottom. now my table displays **C,A,B.** But infact it should have displayed **B,A,C.**

Below is my code

```
if (state == JTTableViewCellEditingStateRight) 
{

   NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

  [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.rows count]-numberOfMoves inSection:0]];  
   [self moveRows];
} 


- (void)moveRows
{

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *selectedString = [self.rows objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];     

    [self.rows removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
    [self.rows insertObject:selectedString atIndex:[self.rows count]];   
}
```

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

let us analyse you code:

```
[self.rows insertObject:selectedString atIndex:[self.rows count]];
```

it seems you put the new item always to the end of the array and not to the new position.

---

the proper way to move the objects is your data source is the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    id _object = [self.rows objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.rows removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.rows insertObject:_object atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

it might helps you.

Comment: Hi holex, u mean I should right the code in this moveRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: and one more thing, my this line of code NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; always returning zero, irrespective of whichever row I select, and I think here its goin wrong

Comment: yep, sorry, I've just copied the line from your code but it is correct now.

Comment: @Ranjit yes, you should put the same code in your application as it is in my answer and you don't need to change the sort of the elements anywhere else. please, try it and tell me if something is still wrong.

Comment: just a sec, I m trying it out, I will get back to u

Comment: the delegate function moverowatIndexPath is not called

Comment: have you set both of the delegates for your `UITableView` properly?